# How to achieve connecting smart contract using web3.js in react native?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumj

I would like to connect smart contracts in react-native

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to take a look on [**Truffle Box**](https://truffle-box.github.io/)

- [Truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle) is a development framework for Ethereum and smart contracts
- Truffle box provides an integration for React using [truffle-contract](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract)

You might need to hack this a little bit to use it with React Native.